# C++ const std::string assignment

Tags: c++, stdstring

What is most appropriate in const std::string assignment/declaration? Using the constructor(e.g., `const std::string WORD("hello");`) or using equal operator(e.g., `const std::string WORD= "hello";`)?
Does these things has difference in memory usage or time processes?

Comment: try it out here and compare the generated assembly http://gcc.godbolt.org/

Comment: Both use constructors. There is no assignment, nor `operator=` used in your shown code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a difference in C++ between copy initialization and direct initialization?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051379/is-there-a-difference-in-c-between-copy-initialization-and-direct-initializati)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any reasonable compiler, the code generated will be the same in both cases. Whether you should use direct initialization or copy-initialization in this case is essentially opinion-based.

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, generally compilers will remove the copies using ["Return Value Optimisation"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) anyway. See this code on ideone [here](http://ideone.com/lYNZ3k) calls neither the ordinary constructor nor the assignment operator as it doesn't print that they're being called to screen:

That is:

```
#include <iostream>

class C
{
    public:
    C() {}
    C(const char[]) { std::cout << "Ordinary Constructor" << std::endl; }
    C& operator=(const char[]) { std::cout << "Assignment Operator" << std::endl; return *this; }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "Start" << std::endl;
    C x1 = "Hello";
    C x2("Hello");
    std::cout << "End" << std::endl;
}
```

Simply outputs:

```
Start
End
```

It doesn't output:

```
Start
Assignment Operator
Ordinary Constructor
End
```

As C++ allows the copies to be skipped and the temporary to be constructed in place.

Comment: It would never call assignment operator here because both x1 and x2 are initialized, they are not assigned.

Comment: `C x1 = "Hello";` means copy constructor, not assignment operator

Answer (score 0):

The lines:

```
std::string x = "hello";
std::string x("hello");
```

both will only call the constructor of `std::string`. That is, they are identical, and neither will use the `operator=` overloads.