# What is difference between int a=985 and int a(985)

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int a=985;
    cout << a;
}
```

Second is

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int a(985);
    cout << a;
}
```

Hi What is difference between int a(985) and int a=985. Mean any logic between these methods of value assignment? Same for char and string etc..

Comment: There's no real difference between them, at least not for `int` or other intrinsic types.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051379/is-there-a-difference-in-c-between-copy-initialization-and-direct-initializati

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference. Both

```
T t = to;
```

and

```
T t (to);
```

for some other `T to` copy constructs `t` from `to`. If `to` and `t` have different types, things get more complicated, e.g. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051379/is-there-a-difference-in-c-between-copy-initialization-and-direct-initializati).

Comment: sorry little confused you mean a(985) 985 is copying to a?

Comment: @AsifMushtaq Basically yes. For value-like types like `int` both will set the LHS to the value of the RHS. For more complex types, both will still do the same if the LHS and the RHS have the same type, just probably something more complex.