# Template cast operator when T is QPointF

Tags: c++, qt, templates, casting

I have a custom two dimensional point type, which has a template cast operator:

```
struct MyPoint
{
    double x, y;

    template < typename T >
    operator T() const
    {
        return T{ x, y };
    }
};
```

All works fine for `std` types:

```
auto p1 = MyPoint{ 1, 2 };
auto p2 = static_cast< std::array< double, 2 > >( p1 );
auto p3 = static_cast< std::pair< double, double > >( p1 );
```

But if I try the same thing with `QPointF`, I get this error (using g++ v4.8):

```
../CppTest/main.cpp:23:42: error: call of overloaded 'QPointF(MyPoint&)' is ambiguous
     auto p3 = static_cast< QPointF >( p1 );
                                          ^
../CppTest/main.cpp:23:42: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/QPointF:1:0,
                 from ../CppTest/main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qpoint.h:270:18: note: constexpr QPointF::QPointF(const QPoint&)
 Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline QPointF::QPointF(const QPoint &p) : xp(p.x()), yp(p.y()) { }
                  ^
/usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qpoint.h:205:46: note: constexpr QPointF::QPointF(const QPointF&)
 class Q_CORE_EXPORT QPointF
                                              ^
/usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qpoint.h:205:46: note: constexpr QPointF::QPointF(QPointF&&)
```

It's like the compiler isn't even attempting to use the cast operator.  If I change to an implicit conversion, such as:

```
QPointF p3 = p1;
```

It works fine.  It also works if I use `QPoint` - it just seems to be `QPointF` that is causing problems, and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell the issue is that `QPointF` provides a constructor which takes a `QPoint`.
When you do a `static_cast` the compiler tries to call `QPointF(MyPoint&)` and it sees two ways to create a `QPointF` from `MyPoint`:

- Use the constructor taking a `QPoint`, by converting `MyPoint` to a `QPoint` first
- Use any of the existing constructors that take a `QPointF` by converting `MyPoint` to a `QPointF` first.

Since there is more than one choice it is ambigous.

The copy initialization works because `p1` is first converted to a `QPointF` and then the copy constructor is called.

The differences between `QPointF p(...)` and `QPointF p = ...` are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051379/is-there-a-difference-in-c-between-copy-initialization-and-direct-initializati).

To illustrate the point following is a small example which exhibits the same issue:

```
#include <iostream>

struct MyType
{
    template < typename T >
    operator T() const
    {
        return T{};
    }
};

struct A
{
    A() {}
    A(const A &) {}
};

struct B
{
    B() {}
    B(const A &) {}
    B(const B &) {}
};

int main()
{
    auto my = MyType{};
    auto a1 = static_cast<A>(my);
    //auto b1 = static_cast<B>(my); // fails
    B b2 = my;
}
```