# Difference between T t {x} and T t = { x } for integral or enumeration type?

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer, c++14

In C++14:

For any integral or enumeration type `T` and for any expression `expr`:

Is there ever a difference between:

```
struct S { T t { expr }; };
```

and

```
struct S { T t = { expr }; };
```

**Update:**

I got to `[dcl.init.list]p3b5` which says:

> If the initializer list has a single element of type E and either T is not a reference type or its referenced type is reference-related to E, the object or reference is initialized from that element.

I believe this quote applies to both *direct-list-initialization* and *copy-list-initialization*.

So I think the answer is no, there is no difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take a look at [direct initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) and [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) references, you will find the same words:

> if T is a non-class type, standard conversions are used, if necessary, to convert the value of other to the cv-unqualified version of T

so there should be no difference. The difference of these initializations only applies for class types: *copy initialization* does *not* consider `explicit` constructors and `explicit` user-defined conversion operators, *direct initialization* does. Integral and enumeration types have neither of them.

**Edit:**
[@ᐅ Johannes Schaub - litb ᐊ answered a relative question to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1051468/3552770) (only about parentheses, instead of braces) and he referenced `8.5/14` with similar wording (emphasis mine):

> **The form of initialization (using parentheses or =) is generally
>   insignificant, but does matter when the initializer or the entity
>   being initialized has a class type**; see below. If the entity being
>   initialized does not have class type, the expression-list in a
>   parenthesized initializer shall be a single expression.

I could not find the `{}` counterpart in the standard, either. I hope that this is enough arguments to support the **there's no difference** answer.

Comment: Your link is about parentheses, not braces.  It's not clear that the same arguments hold here.

Comment: I thought the first half of my answer was enough. I still hope that there's a consistency in effects between `()` vs `= ()` and `{}` vs `= {}`.

Comment: Well, `{}` vs `={}` is consistent with user expectations, not with `()` vs `=()`;  Consider: `volatile int x = 42; char a(char(x)); char b = (char(x)); char c{char(x)}; char d = {char{x}};`

Comment: Please, point out the difference. You're asking me for too much.

Comment: `a` is not an initialized variable, it's a function.

Comment: Well, that was a catch question. That doesn't happen with braces and the original question isn't about parentheses, so why are you asking me about them? Should I remove the **Edit** part?

Comment: If you want to quote something about parentheses, I would at least say that the question Johannes answered is *similar*, not identical.

Comment: I can agree with that, I'm not a native English speaker, so I wrote a sloppy sentence.

Answer (score 1):

1. `struct S {T t { expr };};`  is a non-static data member initializer
   that **does not use the equals sign**.
2. `struct S{T t = { expr };};` is a non-static data member initializer
   that **uses the equals sign**.

The first case is a *direct-list-initialization* while the second is a *copy-list-initialization*.

The difference between *direct-list-initialization* and *copy-list-initialization* is that for the first case **both** explicit and non-explicit constructors are considered, while for the second **only** non-explicit constructors may be called.

To clarify, consider the following example:

```
struct Foo {
  int i;
  explicit Foo(int i_) : i(i_) {}
};

struct Bar {
  Foo f {1};  
};
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/247e135b7e748e60)

In this example `Foo` has an `explicit` constructor and `Bar` direct initializes its member `f` of type `Foo`. The example code compiles fine since for direct initialization both `explicit` and `non-explicit` constructors are considered.

Now we alter the example by transforming the non-static data member initializer with no use of equal sign, that is a case of direct-list-initialization to a non-static data member initializer with use of equal sign, which is a case of copy-list-initialization.

```
struct Foo {
  int i;
  explicit Foo(int i_) : i(i_) {}
};

struct Bar {
  Foo f = {1};  
};
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/375831085e13e846)

Now the above example doesn't compile and emits an error:

> error: chosen constructor is explicit in copy-initialization

This is expected because as already been mentioned in copy-list-initialization only non-explicit constructors may called.

**Now for enumerators and other integral types, the difference displayed above won't apply (i.e., no constructors are involved). As such, the two statements (i.e., [1] and [2]) would be equivalent.**

But for completeness sake, lets consider the following examples:

```
enum class Foo {A, B, C};

struct Bar {
  Foo f{Foo::A};  
};
```

and

```
enum class Foo {A, B, C};

struct Bar {
  Foo f = {Foo::A};  
};
```

Both the examples compile fine.

Also consider the following examples:

```
struct Bar {
  int i {1};  
};
```

and

```
struct Bar {
  int i = {1};  
};
```

Both examples also compile fine.

Comment: "Compiles fine" and "no difference in side-effects" are not equivalent statements.

Comment: The compiles fine is to illustrate that for built in types the difference mentioned doesn't apply. Consequently, for built in type there's no difference in side-effects.