# Confusion in copy initialization and direct initialization

Tags: c++, initialization, implicit-conversion

Consider simple statement (Taken from [Is there a difference in C++ between copy initialization and direct initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051379/is-there-a-difference-in-c-between-copy-initialization-and-direct-initializati)):

```
A c2 = A();
```

> This statement value-initializes a temporary and then copies that
>   value into c2 (Read 5.2.3/2 and 8.5/14). **This of course will require a
>   non-explicit copy constructor (Read 8.5/14 and 12.3.1/3 and
>   13.3.1.3/1)**

[Mind the bold sentence in above para] -> My question is why?

Now consider this code :

```
class B {};
struct A 
{
  A(B const&) {}
  A(A const&) = delete;
  //A(A const&); //delete above statement and uncomment this statement, 
  //and everything works, even though there in no body of copy constructor Oo
};

A a2 = B();    //error since there is no copy constructor oO
```

Why copy-initialization requires presence of copy constructor even though it's not needed sometime as presented in above code

**Please please one more thing** :

> While direct initialization has all constructors available to call,
>   and in addition can do any **implicit conversion** it needs to match up
>   argument types, copy initialization can just set up one **implicit
>   conversion sequence**.

[**Mind the bolding in the following para**]

Doesn't that means direct initialization have access to all constructors and can perform **implicit conversion sequence** , while copy initialization all can do is perform **implicit conversion sequence**? . What I mean to ask is , implicit conversion in direct initialization is different from implicit conversion sequence in copy initialization ?

Comment: Since C++11 this is a copy/move context, so move constructor will be preferred to copy constructor. (This doesn't really affect your question)

Comment: In `A c2 = A();`, you say "why is a copy constructor needed?"  Please explain how you think the `A()` object's value is transferred into the object `c2`  , if not by a copy constructor.

Comment: For your second question read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12953129/1505939).  The version with `A(A const&);` is ill-formed with no diagnostic required because it violates the One Definition Rule  (there must be one body for each function that is *odr-used*, however your program has none)

Comment: @M.M Thanks a lot sir for your helping comments, can you please also answer my last question with line "Please please one more thing : " ? . If possible can you please turn your comments into an answer? Thanks

Comment: The last one is really a separate question, you should have posted two different ones. ALso I don't understand the question

Answer (score 0):

The rules for evaluating

```
A a1 = B();   // (1) copy-initialization
A a2 = {B()}; // (2) copy-initialization
A a3{B()};    // (3) direct-initialization
```

come from [[dcl.init]/17](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17):

> — If the initializer is a (non-parenthesized) *braced-init-list*, the object or reference is list-initialized (8.5.4).
>   —  [...]
>   — If the destination type is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type:
>
> - If the initialization is direct-initialization, or if it is copy-initialization where the cv-unqualified
>     version of the source type is the same class as, or a derived class of, the class of the destination,
>     constructors are considered. [...]
> - Otherwise (i.e., for the remaining copy-initialization cases), user-defined conversion sequences
>     that can convert from the source type to the destination type or (when a conversion function
>     is used) to a derived class thereof are enumerated as described in 13.3.1.4, and the best one is
>     chosen through overload resolution (13.3). [...] The result of the call (which is the temporary for the constructor case) is then used to direct-initialize, according to the rules above,
>     the object that is the destination of the copy-initialization. In certain cases, an implementation
>     is permitted to eliminate the copying inherent in this direct-initialization by constructing the
>     intermediate result directly into the object being initialized; see 12.2, 12.8.

For both `a2` and `a3`, the initializer is a *braced-init-list*, so we just do list-initialization. This ends up calling the `B const&` constructor.

For `a1`, the first sub-bullet doesn't apply - since the source type (`B`) is not the same or derived class of the destination type (`A`). So we go into the second sub-bullet point which involves considering conversion functions. There is one (`A(B const&)`) so we effectively rewrite the expression

```
A a1_new{A{B{}}};
```

Now typically, this extra copy will be elided. But you're explicitly prohibiting it, so the code cannot compile.

---

As to **why** the differentiation? I don't know. It seems like copy-initialization should simply be syntactic sugar for direct-initialization. In most cases, after all, it is...

Comment: `A a1_new(A(B()));` is most vexing parse

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Blah, just turned everything into braces.

Comment: "*It seems like copy-initialization should simply be syntactic sugar for direct-initialization. In most cases, after all, it is...*" The prvalue changes in C++17 ensure it always is, no?

Comment: @ildjarn No. I should probably delete that <s>rant</s> paragraph anyway. It's not like we want `std::vector<int> v = 3;` to compile...

Answer (score 0):

(The following applies to C++11)To avoid rambling too much, `A a2 = B();` has two stage : first, A temp object of type `B` is created when you write `B()`. Then, your function `A(B const&) {}` will not be invoked here with the role of **directly** initializing A because you use the copy-initialization syntax. If you want to invoke it to **directly** initialize A, you should write `A a2(B())` instead, rather than using the copy-initialization syntax(the devil here is `=`). So, what's next? You get a temp object of type `B`, and you want to use it to initialize obj of type `A`, and now, you **indirectly** initialize `A` by converting `B()` to the type `A`. **So your function `A(B const&) {}` is used as a type conversion rather than directly initializing A.**

Because of conversion, a temp obj of type A is created, and then we need copy constructor to initialize `a2` using that temporary obj.

In copy initialization, type-conversion-functions with `explicit` keyword can't be called. The design philosophy of `explicit` keyword is that you should directly invoke it. Combined with type-conversion-functions, those `explicit` attributed functions should not be used for implicit type conversion. In direct initialization, they can all be called even they are `explicit`.

To make things interesting, if you make your copy constructor and move constructor `explicit`, you can't even write `T obj = T{}`, but you can write `T obj {T{}}`. You can view copy and move ctor as a conversion too, only the destination and source type are of the same class.

I would like to provide you with further readings [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization). After that, read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51257847/copy-initialization-why-move-or-copy-constructor-was-not-called-even-if-copy-e) to know about copy-list-initialization and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50100705/c-initializenew-an-array-of-vector-of-different-initial-size) to learn about aggregate-types.

Comment: N.b. this all applies to C++14 and prior; C++17 changes the rules.

Comment: yeah, I shall mention it.