# C++ : initialize(new) an array of vector of different initial size

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, initialization, initializer-list

To help you get the point, I give my codes:(main.cpp),only one file involved.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class test{
public : 
    int member {0};
    void fun(){cout << "member is " << member << endl;}
    test(){}
    //test(int param) : member(param){} //this line is commented.
};

int main()
{
    vector<test> *vp = new vector<test>[2] {{10},{20}};
    //vector<test> array[2] {{10},{20}};//this won't work either.
    cout << "size of vp[0] is " << vp[0].size() << endl;
    cout << "size of vp[1] is " << vp[1].size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I intend to initialize `vp[0]` to size 10 and `vp[1]` to size `20`. However when I compiled it on `mac` using `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main` it complained:

```
main.cpp:14:45: error: chosen constructor is explicit in copy-initialization
    vector<test> *vp = new vector<test>[2] {{10},{20}};
                                            ^~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:517:14: note: 
      constructor declared here
    explicit vector(size_type __n);
             ^
main.cpp:14:50: error: chosen constructor is explicit in copy-initialization
    vector<test> *vp = new vector<test>[2] {{10},{20}};
                                                 ^~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:517:14: note: 
      constructor declared here
    explicit vector(size_type __n);
         ^
```

In CentOS Linux using the same command and I got

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:14:54: error: converting to ‘std::vector<test>’ from initializer list would use explicit constructor ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type, const allocator_type&) [with _Tp = test; _Alloc = std::allocator<test>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::allocator_type = std::allocator<test>]’
     vector<test> *vp = new vector<test>[2] {{10},{20}};
                                                      ^
main.cpp:14:54: error: converting to ‘std::vector<test>’ from initializer list would use explicit constructor ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type, const allocator_type&) [with _Tp = test; _Alloc = std::allocator<test>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::allocator_type = std::allocator<test>]’
```

What is going on here? Why does it have anything to do with keyword `explicit`?
I know vector have several constructors(such as the one with initializer-list type argument). If I initialize the vector like `vector<test> temp {10}`, this would initialize vector to be of size 10 without any `explicit` concerns. I don't know what is hidden inside when it comes to `vector<test> array[2] {{10},{20}}` that cause me the bug.

Interestingly, if I provide class `test` with a constructor with one argument(just uncomment the line in my code), the compiler does not complain at all. But the meaning of `vector<test> array[2] {{10},{20}}` changed to initialize the vector `array[0]` with 2 `test` type objects initialized with `10` and `20` respectively. But the syntax `vector<test> array[2] {10,20}`,which i tried later, is wrong again.

I don't know what is going on here and am totally lost. Isn't `{10,20}` of initializer-list type too?

I really appreciate it if you can explain what's going on here, and how to initialize an array of vector of different size(please do not use circumventing ways). I want to know what does the syntax means exactly.

Comment: For starters don't use a pointer to vector and don't use `new`. Use vector of objects and let it do all the allocations.

Comment: There is a dupe for this. The gist is list initialization doesn't allow direct initialization

Comment: @Ron Thanks! I really appreciate it if you can explain a little about what's going on here.

Comment: `vector<test> *vp = new vector<test>[2] {{10},{20}};` -> `std::vector<std::vector<test>> data = {std::vector<test>(10), std::vector<test>(20)};`

Comment: @PasserBy Thanks! I did search before asking.

Comment: I can't find it either, no idea what the post was called

Comment: @PasserBy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723164/why-does-stdvectorint-b2-create-a-1-element-vector-and-not-a-2-element?

Comment: @HanXIAO I'd like to point you to these [C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and [vector reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: @PasserBy Thanks! If list initialization doesn't allow direct initialization, why `vector<test> obj {10}` can initialize a vector of size `10` if class `test` does not have a constructor with one argument? Besides, if class `test` have a constructor with one argument, why the same syntax `vector<test> obj {10}` in this time initialize the vector of size 1 with 1 `test` type object initiate by `10`?

Comment: @NathanOliver Not that one. I meant this exact question, where a type has explicit constructor and a vector of them cannot be simply initialized with nested `{}`.

Comment: @Ron Thanks! Actually I came up this question when I am reading Stroustrup's Principles and Practice Using C++.

Comment: I meant the list of parameters within `{}` is used to copy initialize the `initializer_list`'s elements

Comment: OK, I think maybe I should keep on reading and save this question later...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, `explicit` constructor is allowed in direct-initialization, but not copy-initialization.

Then, in [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization),

(emphasis mine)

> Each `direct public base, (since C++17)` array element, or non-static class member, in order of array subscript/appearance in the class definition, is **copy-initialized** from the corresponding clause of the initializer list.

That means for `new vector<test>[2] {{10},{20}};`, `{10}` and `{20}` are used to *copy-initialize* the `vector<test>` elements; then the `explicit` constructors are not considered.

And

> If I initialize the vector like `vector<test> temp {10}`, this would initialize vector to be of size 10 without any `explicit` concerns.

Because `explicit` constructor is allowed in [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization#Notes),

> Direct-initialization is more permissive than copy-initialization: copy-initialization only considers non-explicit constructors and non-explicit user-defined conversion functions, while direct-initialization considers all constructors and all user-defined conversion functions.

For the same reason `new vector<test>[2] {std::vector<test>{10},std::vector<test>{20}};` works too.

BTW:

> if I provide class `test` with a constructor with one argument(just uncomment the line in my code), the compiler does not complain at all.

If you provide a constructor which could be used to convert `int` to `test` implicitly, then `{10}` could be used to construct an `std::initializer_list<test>`, then the constructor of `std::vector<test>` which taking `std::initializer_list<test>` is invoked because it's always preferred. BTW If you make the constructor of `test` `explicit` the code would fail too.

Answer (score 2):

You are initializing `vector<test>` objects with the code: `vector<test> array[2] {{10},{20}}`. The error you're getting is from using the [`vector::vector(size_t count)` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) which is `explicit`. This `vector` constructor would construct `count` default constructed `test` objects.
So for example if this hadn't been defined as `explicit` you would have ended up with `array[0]` containing 10 default constructed `test` objects, and `array[1]` containing 20 default constructed `test` object. If you had intended to do this you would have to have constructed the `vector` objects explicitly:

```
vector<test> foo[] = { vector<test>{ 10 }, vector<test>{ 20 } }
```

You really wanted to construct test objects into the `vector`s so this `eplicit` is in fact protecting you from accidentally ending up allocating unintended `vector`s.

When you add in the `test:test(int param)` constructor `{{10},{20}}` still fails to use the `explicit` `vector` constructor. But this can now be treated as [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) of `vector[0]`. But similarly to if you'd done: `int array[2] = {42}` and the 2<sup>nd</sup> element would be zero-initialized; so too your 2<sup>nd</sup> `vector` will be uninitialized in this case.