# copy initialization : why move or copy constructor was not called even if copy-elision is turned off?

Tags: c++, initialization, implicit-conversion, copy-elision, copy-initialization

My question is different because I may "know" copy-elision. I am learning copy initialization. However,the following code confused me because I have already turned off the copy-elision using `-fno-elide-contructors -O0` option.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class test{
public :
    test(int a_, int b_) : a{a_}, b{b_} {}
    test(const test& other)
    {
        cout << "copy constructor" << endl;
    }
    test& operator=(const test& other)
    {
        cout << "copy assignment" << endl;
        return *this;
    }
    test(test&& other)
    {
        cout << "move constructor" << endl;
    }
    test& operator=(test&& other)
    {
        cout <<"move assignment" << endl;
        return *this;
    }

private :
    int a;
    int b;
};

test show_elide_constructors()
{
    return test{1,2};
}

int main()
{
    cout << "**show elide constructors**" <<endl;
    show_elide_constructors();
    cout << "**what is this?**" <<endl;
    test instance = {1,2};//why neither move constructor nor copy constructor is not called?
    cout << "**show move assignment**" <<endl;
    instance = {3,4};
    return 0;
}
```

I first build with the command:
`g++ -std=c++11 -fno-elide-constructors -O0 main.cpp -o main` and I got the result as following:

```
**show elide constructors**
move constructor
**what is this?**
**show move assignment**
move assignment
```

Then I built with command without `-fno-elide-constructor -O0` option to attest that `g++` indeed turned off the optimization in my previous build.

So, why `test instance = {1,2}` does not call copy constructor or move constructor? Isn't a temp object created from the implicit conversion? And `instance` is supposed to be initialized by that temp object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> why `test instance = {1,2}` does not call copy constructor or move constructor?

It shouldn't. `test instance = {1,2}` is [copy-list-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#Explanation), as the effect, the appropriate constructor (i.e. `test::test(int, int)`) is used to construct the object `instance` directly. No needs to construct a temporary and call copy/move constructor here.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I add some supplementary information here.
: [Copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization), [List initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#Explanation).

So `T object = {other}` is indeed copy initialization until c++11, which consider it as list initialization.

BTW, if the constructor is explicit, the call would fail.