# What is the difference between initializing with = and initializing with {}?

Tags: c++, c++11

You can initialize a variable using = . For example:

```
int a = 1000;
```

C++ 11 introduced an extra notation {} . For example:

```
int a {1000};
```

According to Programming: Principles and Practices by Bjarne Stroustrup:

> C++11 introduced an initialization notation that outlaws narrowing conversions.

I wanted to check out this cool feature. And I typed a piece of code twice:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"     |     #include "std_lib_facilities.h" 
                                    |
int main()                          |     int main()
                                    |
{                                   |     {
    int x = 254;                    |         int x {254};
    char y = x;                     |         char y {x};
    int z = y;                      |         int z {y};
                                    |
    cout << "x = " << x << '\n'     |         cout << "x = " << x << '\n'
         << "y = " << y << '\n'     |              << "y = " << y << '\n'
         << "z = " << z << '\n';    |              << "z = " << z << '\n';
                                    |
}                                   |     }
```

The code on the left uses = whereas the code on the right uses {}

But the code on the right hand side loses some information even after using {}. Thus the output is same in both pieces of code:

> x = 254
>
> y = ■
>
> z = -2

So, what's the difference between initializing with = and initializing with {} ?

EDIT: My question may or may not be a duplicate. I'm just a beginner and I do not even understand the code of the possibly original question. I'm no judge. Even if it's a duplicate, I cannot understand any answers of that question. I feel that this question should be treated as an original one since I would understand simple language opposed to some high-level words of that question's answer.

Comment: And where, exactly, do you expect a "narrowing conversion" to fail in the right example? The initialization of `char` with a positive number larger than `CHAR_MAX` on your machine?

Comment: `char` (in your system) default to `signed char` (but note that `signed char` != `char`). `254` is a valid `char` (no narrowing conversion, its numeric value doesn't matter) but converting back to `int` you get it negative because of sign. To see what's changed try `unsigned char k = {260};` vs `unsigned char k = 260;`

Comment: If you use `gcc` add `-Werror=narrowing` command line option to outlaw the narrowing conversions.

Comment: Adriano Repetti, I did stuff as you said. I think I must have made an error somewhere because the new source code did not work. I'm a beginner, so I have no idea about unsigned and signed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a difference in C++ between copy initialization and direct initialization?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051379/is-there-a-difference-in-c-between-copy-initialization-and-direct-initializati)

Comment: Davidhigh, I have made a few edits.

Comment: @Superex: just to clarify, that means no offense. Your question is valid. It's just that `{ ... }` corresponds to [direct-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) and `= ...` to [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization), and the comparison between the two has already been treated here on SO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What is the difference between initializing with `=` and initializing with `{}`?

In general, the difference is that the former is [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) and the latter is [direct](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) - [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization). The linked online reference describes all three forms of initialization in detail. In particular, there is the difference that you already quoted; List initialization may not be used with narrowing conversions.

> But the code on the right hand side loses some information even after using `{}`

The program on the right side is ill-formed.

As mentioned, the standard does not allow narrowing [conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast) in the context of list initialization. `int` to `char` is a narrowing conversion.

Because the program is ill-formed, the standard does not guarantee its behaviour except that a compiler is required to emit a diagnostic message. For example, g++-5.3.0 will say:

```
warning: narrowing conversion of 'x' from 'int' to 'char' inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
```

> May you please elaborate on the "ill-formed" part?

Standard says that the program shall not do X. Your program does X. Therefore it violates the standard which makes the program ill-formed. Here, X is:

> If a narrowing conversion (see below) is required to convert any of the arguments, the program is ill-formed.

---

The program on the left is not ill-formed. However it, just like the program on the right side, does assign a value to `char y` that is not representable by the `char` type (it could be representable in some implementation where `char` is an unsigned type, but given the output, that appears not to be the case for your implementation). When an unrepresentable value is converted to a signed type, the resulting value is implementation defined.

Comment: Yep, I got that warning message! May you please elaborate on the "ill-formed" part? Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: @Superex I added a simple explanation for ill-formedness.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating on that part. But I have used a library (std_lib_facilities.h)  that has been suggested by the book. So I doubt that program may be ill-formed.

Comment: @Superex why do you think that including that header prevents your program from being ill-formed? It does not. You said that you got the warning message. The warning implies that your program is ill-formed.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment. I accidentally copy-pasted the wrong diagnostics. But I did get what you mentioned in another similar experiment.