# c++ initializer difference, with and without = operator

Tags: c++11

What is difference between initializing `x1` and `x2`?

```
struct X {
    int i;
};

void func(){
    X x1 = {2};
    X x2 {2};

    cout << x1.i << ", " << x2.i << endl;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051379/is-there-a-difference-in-c-between-copy-initialization-and-direct-initializati

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a difference in C++ between copy initialization and direct initialization?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051379/is-there-a-difference-in-c-between-copy-initialization-and-direct-initializati)

Comment: @101010 it doesnt seem relataed.

Comment: @Manoj in that question, () operators used. I have used {} operator.

Comment: oops sorry.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> X x1 = {2};
> ```

Is copy-list-initialization.

> ```
> X x2 {2};
> ```

Is direct-initialization.

---

Both syntaxes perform aggregate initialization, because `X` is an aggregate.

---

> What is difference

Braces can not be elided with the direct-initialization form (until C++14).

In general, copy initialization only considers non-explicit constructors and conversion functions and direct initialization considers also explicit ones. However, this does not apply to aggregate initialization.

---

> with and without = operator

The equals (=) character here isn't actually an operator. It is part of the syntax of copy initialization.

Comment: @UDPLover there is no performance difference between aggregate initialization and aggregate initialization.