# Explicit conversion with Assignment

Tags: c++, constructor, assignment-operator, explicit-conversion

A simple class with explicit conversion constructor.

```
class MyDouble {
    double d;
public:
    MyDouble() : d(0) {}
    explicit MyDouble(double d_) : d(d_) {}
    MyDouble & operator =(double d_) {
        d = d_; return *this;
    }
};
```

I add an assignment on purpose to make it can be assigned constructed from `double`.

```
MyDouble a; 
a = 1.1;                    // this works
MyDouble b = MyDouble(1.1); // this works
MyDouble c(1.1);            // this works
MyDouble d = 1.1;           // this does not work
```

I do not want implicit conversion, cause it will cause some other problems. But I still want direct assignment work, but it does not. Is there anyway to make the last statement `MyDouble d = 1.1;` work without deleting the `explicit` keyword.

Comment: The only *assignment* in your code is `a = 1.1;`. The rest are not assignment. "I do not want implicit conversion"... But `MyDouble d = 1.1;` is clearly an attempt to perform an implicit conversion!

Comment: “Explicit conversion constructor” is an oxymoron: a constructor is _converting_ iff it is not `explicit`.

Comment: `MyDouble d = 1.1`;  Can this be interpreted as construct a new object `d` and assign it as the number `1.1`.

Comment: Consider that barring a new special case in the language, this would allow `vector<int> v = 5;` to compile.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a difference in C++ between copy initialization and direct initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051379/is-there-a-difference-in-c-between-copy-initialization-and-direct-initializati)

Comment: @phynju: No: initialization is not assignment.

Comment: There's always the option of using `auto e = MyDouble{1.1};` That's explicit, and the type is only named once. A user defined literal may even make it nicer to look at.

Comment: @phynju, How is it clearly not right? Built-in types don't have any explicitness requirements.

Comment: I did not notice the type IS `double` @chris

Comment: Quite Clear now. Thank you ALL.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is 'no', there is no way to allow MyDouble d = 1.; without removing the explicit.

You could simply use MyDouble d(1.); or MyDouble d{1.}; instead of using assignment-initialization. That would allow you to retain the explicit while also being clear you are initializing.

Comment: Nit-pick: it is [*copy initialization*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization), not *assignment-initialization*.