# What is the difference between the two initialization: Foo f(); Foo f = Foo()

Tags: c++

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(){}
private:
    Foo(const Foo &);
};

Foo f();
Foo f1 = Foo();
```

I find that when I declare `Foo(const Foo &)` to private, `Foo f1 = Foo();` does not compile。 so I think `Foo f1 = Foo()`; just invoke copy constructor ,but when I change my code to:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(){}
    Foo(const Foo &){std::cout<<"Foo(const Foo &)";}

};

Foo f();
Foo f1 = Foo();
```

It doesn't print anything。So What is the difference between the two initialization: `Foo f(); Foo f = Foo()` ?

Comment: The difference is that the first isn't an initialization. It's a function declaration, just like `int f();`. But that's not really the question.

Answer (score 5):

Due to [*copy elision*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) the copy-constructor doesn't have to be called. The copy-constructor must still exist as a public member though.

And `Foo f();` declares a *function* named `f`, taking no arguments and returning a `Foo` object by value.

Comment: In C++17 the copy constructor is no longer required.

Comment: And before C++17 the copy constructor must not be `explicit`.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the actual question, formally, the code

```
Foo f1 = Foo();
```

uses the default constructor to create a temporary object of type `Foo` and uses the copy constructor to construct `f1` as a copy of that temporary object, then it destroys the temporary object.

```
Foo f;
```

uses the default constructor to create `f`.

That little dance with the copy constructor isn't as inefficient as it sounds. Back in the olden days, as long as the copy constructor was accessible, the compiler was allowed to skip the temporary, and directly initialize `f1`. This is referred to as "copy elision". The resulting code is the same as `Foo f1;`. However, if `Foo` did not have a copy constructor, or the constructor was not accessible at the point of the initialization (for example, the copy constructor is private and the initialization is not done inside a member function), then the code was not valid.

Then copy elision became mandatory: the compiler is no longer just **allowed** to skip the temporary; it's **required** to.

And now, apparently, it's no longer even required that the copy constructor exist and be accessible; the compiler is required to transform the first form into the second, so the two are **identical**.

Answer (score 0):

[for now I don't have the rep to post image](https://i.ibb.co/1qbGYBs/image-2024-02-18-134049652.png)

1. Take a look at this, a clip of 'Timur' brother, from his 2019 Talk on Initializations:- https://youtube.com/clip/Ugkx_02Xe8XehKLdhz7Zz-EG5pc-Wkvm6mEp
2. You are absolutely right<sup>[1]</sup>, This behavior was fixed in `C++17`

---

3. before `C++17`, The behavior you were facing, was just one of those 'Corner-Cases' that the ISO C++ Standard didn't talk about. (a.k.a ISO C++ Standard didn't ***'REQUIRE'*** compilers to be "OPTIMIZED".)
4. What do I mean you ask? - So basically, before C++17, you & I could just decide to write a ***'SILLY_COMPILER'*** --> which doesn't optimize &

    thus calls:-----> I. CONSTRUCTOR for `tmp_obj` ----> II. COPY_CONSTRUCT-ing `f` from `tmp_obj`

   - 4.1. & that ***'SILLY_COMPILER'*** would definitely need access to COPY_CONSTRUCTOR......
   - 4.2. same way   `Foo f1 = f;` would need COPY_CONSTRUCTOR to be public ‍♀️

---

5. FINALLY, The optimization is simply the fact that,

> 'we can just Call the REGULAR-Constructor of `f1` based on the parameters that was passed to `tmp_obj` on the RightHandSide ‍♀️. `tmp_obj` doesn't have to be Initialized at all!'

```
& This has a technical name:-   `Copy Elision`
```

---

[1]:- 'right' to speculate that smth's maybe wrong . & The C++ Gods concurred on the same thought of yours, & made changes in C++17

[Another Great Answer on this can be found here:- [Is there a difference between copy-initialization and direct-initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051379/is-there-a-difference-between-copy-initialization-and-direct-initialization)]

[NOTE:- 
`Foo f();` --> DIRECT_INIT 
`Foo f1 = Foo();` --> COPY_INIT]