# Initializing objects in c++

Tags: c++, object, initialization

There are multiple ways of initializing an object in c++. There are two examples below, ent1 and ent2. I'm wondering what the difference is, and is one of them more 'correct' or preferred over another?

```
class Entity {
public:
    int h;
    Entity(int health) : h(health) { }
}

Entity ent1(10);

Entity ent2 = Entity(10);
```

Comment: In this context they are identical, and the first one is preferred.

Comment: Why is the first one preferred?

Comment: Because there is no pointless repetition.

Comment: Makes sence. You say 'in this context they are identical'. In what context will they NOT be identical? Because it's weird that there are 2 ways of making an object if they are identical

Comment: One difference is that the second form requires a copy constructor pre-C++17. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051379/is-there-a-difference-between-copy-initialization-and-direct-initialization.

Comment: Some people prefer `auto ent3 = Entity(10);`

Answer (score 2):

In C++17, both of these are identical.  Pre C++17, however, there is a subtle difference as follows:

The one below is a copy constructor.  This will create an anonymous Entity and then copy over to `ent2`, although the copy may be omitted subject to [copy epsilon](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).

```
Entity ent2 = Entity(10);
```

The one below is a direct instantiation, the memory for `ent1` will be allocated and value 10 will be placed in the area specified by the constructor.

```
Entity ent1(10);
```

The reason direct is preferred, in pre C++17, is because it doesn't require the extra copy step.  This advantage is non-existent in C++17.

Comment: I am pretty sure the standard says the first one is _not_ copied.  It _looks_ like it would be, but it is in fact treated exactly the same as the second.

Comment: The copy was most likely elided pre-C++17, and in C++17 it is guaranteed to be elided.

Comment: It's not "epsilon"

Comment: @juanchopanza in C++17 there is not even a copy to elide, these two syntaxes both specify a variable constructed from argument `10`