# C++ unique_ptr initialization

Tags: c++, initialization

I have question. Let's have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class Writable {
public:
    virtual ~Writable() = default;
    virtual void write(std::ostream& out) const = 0;
};

class String : public Writable {
public:
    String(const std::string& str) : m_str(str) {}
    virtual ~String() override = default;
    virtual void write(std::ostream& out) const override { out << m_str << '\n'; }
private:
    std::string m_str;
};

class Number : public Writable {
public:
    Number(double num) : m_num(num) {}
    virtual ~Number() override = default;
    virtual void write(std::ostream& out) const override { out << m_num << '\n'; }
private:
    double m_num;
};

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<Writable> str1(new String("abc"));
    std::unique_ptr<Writable> num1(new Number(456));

    str1->write(std::cout);
    num1->write(std::cout);
}
```

I dont understand why unique_pointers are defined like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<Writable> str1(new String("abc"));
```

Its some kind of shorthand? Or I must do it this way? Is there some kind of equivalent? For example like:

```
std::unique_ptr<Writable> str1 = std::unique_ptr<String>(new String("abc"));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you are creating a new `unique_ptr` and initializing with a raw pointer returned by `new` operator.

```
std::unique_ptr<Writable> str1(new String("abc"));
```

Here you are creating a new `unique_ptr` and initializing with a raw pointer returned by `new` operator and move constructing another `unique_ptr` with it.

```
std::unique_ptr<Writable> str1 = std::unique_ptr<String>(new String("abc"));
```

However compiler can (most likely) perform move elison and make the above two equivalent.

The right way to initialize from c++14 and later is below

```
std::unique_ptr<Writable> v1 = std::make_unique<String>();
```

Answer (score 1):

The form of initialization in

```
std::unique_ptr<Writable> str1(new String("abc"));
```

is called [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization). If the constructor is marked [`explicit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) (like in [`explicit unique_ptr(pointer p) noexcept`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) constructor), this form of initialization is required.

`explicit` constructor disables [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) in the form of `std::unique_ptr<Writable> str1 = new String("abc");`.

Answer (score 0):

Just like you can write

```
std::vector<int> foo(10);
```

to create a vector of 10 `int`'s

```
std::unique_ptr<Writable> str1(new String("abc"))
```

creates a `std::unique_ptr<Writable>` that points to a `new String("abc")`.  It is the same as doing

```
std::vector<int> foo = std::vector(10);
```

and

```
std::unique_ptr<Writable> str1 = std::unique_ptr<String>(new String("abc"));
```

except that the later cases use copy initialization [which can be different in some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051379/is-there-a-difference-between-copy-initialization-and-direct-initialization).

---

To save on some typing you could use

```
auto str1 = std::make_unique<String>("abc");
```

instead when you declare your `unique_ptr`'s