# How to correctly initialize a Struct in c++

Tags: c++, struct

Currently running into an issue with this question in my homework. I believe that only 4,7 are incorrect (In Visual Studio they don't throw an error). But i'm honestly not sure why they are the only ones. Since 3 works, I assumed they would work as well but that seems to not be the case. Any advice?

```
struct A {
    double x;
    A(double x = 1) : x(x) { }
};

struct B {
    double x;
    B(A a = 2.0) : x(a.x) { }
};

struct C {
    double x;
    C(B b = B(3)) : x(b.x) { }
};

int main() {
    A a; // (1)
    A a = 4; // (2)
    B b; // (3)
    B b = 5; // (4)
    B b(a); // (5) (a is an object of class A)
    C c; // (6)
    C c = 6.0; // (7)
    C c(a); // (8) (a is an object of class A)
    C c(b); // (9) (b is an object of class B)
}
```

Correct ones are:

a) 1-3

b) 1-3,5,9

c) 1-6,8,9

d) 1-7

e) 1-3,5,6,9

f) none

My reasoning:

1) Correct, just default constructor

2)Correct, constructor default or value (4)

3) Correct, default constructor

4) Incorrect, No constructor for an int

5) Correct, exists constructor for object of type A

6) Correct, Default

7)Incorrect, same as 4

8) This one i'm not sure on, there is no constructor for objects of type A, so I would say incorrect

9) Correct, constructor exists.

This is my reasoning in any case, but i'm not sure where i'm going wrong.

Comment: Please format this code a bit better, I can't make heads or tails out of it.

Comment: *Why* do you think the cases 4 and 7 are incorrect? Why do you think the others are correct?

Comment: g++ claims 4 and 7 as incorrect (with little explanations): [**coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee6b8c87ef567d3d).

Comment: What is the definition of "correct" here? From my point of view none of these are correct because 1) classes with non-trivial constructors should not have any public fields 2) there should be no implicit constructors (especially taking a single argument) 3) initialization should be performed using direct list initialization syntax 4) single letter names should not be used

Comment: What is the question? Do you want to know which of these are right/wrong, or how to fix these problems?

Comment: @AlexM 1) Please [edit] your question to include such information, instead of writing it in the comments. 2) "_No constructor for an int_" But, there exists implicit conversion from an integral value, to floating point value, doesn't it?

Comment: Concerning 8): Following the answer of YSC, `C c(a)` can be constructed by `C::C(B b)` because `B::B(A a)` can be used for conversion of `a` to `class B`, and there is only one user-provided conversion necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rule is, when converting from a type to another (here from/to `int`, `double`, `A`, `B` or `C`): [only one *user-provided conversion* can be used](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion).

This makes indeed `B b = 5;   // (4)` invalid since `5` (an `int`) needs to be:

- converted to `double` (first *standart-conversion*),
- then to a `A` (first *user-defined conversion*),
- then to a `B` (second *user-defined conversion*).

That last one breaks the rule, and this conversion sequence is not legal.

> I'm honestly not sure why they are [ incorrect ].

You can use this rule to check other expressions.

---

Finally, you can impress your teacher with [`std::is_convertible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible):

`std::is_convertible_v<B, C>` returns `true` iff `B` is convertible to `C` ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17b0a14004d9e253)).

Comment: So in that case, 4 and 7 don't work. So I suppose the answer is none?

Comment: I was misunderstanding it as none of the other options, not none of the options. Like a different combination than the ones given is right or wrong. But using the is_convertible shows that A cannot be converted to C, so option e) seems correct in that case.

Comment: @AlexM and if you're still unsure about the difference between `C c = A{}` and `C c{A{}}`, please do ask another question; we'd be happy to answer or point you to it. **edit**: never mind: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1051468/5470596

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the sources/advice :) But if 8 is correct as well that seems to leave me with no correct options. If it was being called as "B b(5);" then it would be option c, but otherwise no option excludes only 4 and 7.

Comment: Haha , that answer is good enough for me  thank you again for all your help !