# Difference between these 2 initialization methods

Tags: c++, memory-management

Suppose I have a class here:

```
class Test
{
    Test(int x, const char* y)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

and I wanted to initialize it. I have 2 methods:

```
Test test(100, "hello world!");
```

and

```
Test test = Test(100, "hello 2nd method!");
```

What are the differences between the 2 and which one is better ( as in faster )

I saw this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051379/is-there-a-difference-between-copy-initialization-and-direct-initialization), but it is for implicit converting the objects.

Comment: But the question you've linked to does cover this. There's no implicit conversions in that question either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### It depends.

In old compilers, the statement `Test test = Test(100, "hello 2nd method!");` would first create a *temporary* `Test` object using your *converting constructor*, and would then use the *copy constructor* to create the `test` object to make a copy of that temporary.

In modern compilers, there is **no difference whatsoever** between these two statements.  The temporary is optimized away by the compiler (see [Copy Elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)) so that the statement `Test test = Test(100, "hello 2nd method!");` does the **exact same thing** as the statement `Test test(100, "hello world!");`.  There is no temporary created anymore.

Comment: Aha. Thank you. I will just stick to the first statement just because it's faster to type and is possibly faster