# what is the difference between the two (type)value and type(value)?

Tags: c++, c

Recently, I am confused with this two expression  - `(type)value` and `type(value)`.

For example :  `size_t c = size_t(-1); size_t c = (size_t)-1;`

what is the difference?

Comment: `type(value)` is not valid C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The former is C++, it's doing [direct initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587070/c-constructor-syntax) by calling a constructor.

The second is C (or C++), it's doing a cast.

So, there's a lot of difference from a C programmer's point of view.

Also, this is a pretty bad idea, since `size_t` is an unsigned type. This should be done using `ssize_t`, which is signed and removes the need for the cast.

Comment: -1 "it's doing direct initialization"; no it's not, that's still a copy initialization. a direct initialization is e.g. `size_t x(-1)`. also, `ssize_t` is not a standard C or C++ type, it's a Posix type. On 32-bit systems and higher the signed type corresponding to `size_t` is (in practice) `ptrdiff_t`. And anyway that's the type to recommend for the purpose where you recommend the Posix-specific type. Third, both are casts, and the effect of the C++ notation cast is defined as equivalent to the C notation cast.

Answer (score 2):

In C, only one of these is a valid expression.

In C++, they are exactly the same, they are two alternative forms of writing an *explicit cast* expression: C-style and the [functional style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474933/what-exactly-is-or-was-the-purpose-of-c-function-style-casts?lq=1).